# Is there an easy way to transfer many, but not all, files to an SD card?

Tags: external-sd, file-transfer

I'm hoping to transfer my photos to a card (then my computer). The problem is the card is too small to handle all of them at once. Is there a way to select say half, or tell it to transfer until it runs out of room? Is there any alternative to selecting thousands of files by hand?

Comment: You could try Termux app. It is a terminal/shell that executes text commands, so you could execute a command to move all files that match a certain pattern to sd-card. Some file manager apps may also allow to select files based of a filename pattern so you don't have to select them by hand.

Comment: adb is the way to go. don't you have usb connection?

Comment: I don't have a usb connection anymore. It broke, I have a samsung...